# how to differentiate between object and array

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let a = {}
let b = []

typeof a // returns an object
typeof b // returns an object

 a === {} // false
 b === [] // false
 a === b // false
```

how then can I know if its an array or object, 
I'm trying to validate user input, where it can either be an array or object but in either Case I don't want the value to be empty

Comment: Both `a === a` and `b === b` are actually true; perhaps you meant that `{} === {}` and `[] === []` are both false (which is expected since `===` does an object reference comparison, and {} and [] both create new objects)

Answer (score 4):

This is really a few questions wrapped up into one. First off, it *is* counter-intuitive for many that `typeof []` is `'object'`. This is simply because an Array is an reference type (`null`, `Date` instances, and any other object references also have `typeof` of `object`).

Thankfully, to know if an object is an instance of `Array`, you can now use the convenient `Array.isArray(...)` function. Alternatively, and you can use this for any type of object, you can do something like `b instanceof Array`.

Knowing if one of these is *empty* can be done by checking `Object.keys(a).length === 0`, though for Arrays it's more natural to do `b.length === 0`.

Checking any two objects variables (including Arrays) with `===` will only tell you if the two variables reference the same object in memory, not if their *contents* are equal.

Comment: `Array.isArray(o)` is a better choice than `o instanceof Array` since the former only returns `true` if `o` is (in specification terms) an _exotic array object_. For example `Array.isArray(Object.setPrototypeOf({}, Array.prototype))` is `false` while `Object.setPrototypeOf({}, Array.prototype) instanceof Array` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Since both Arrays and Objects share the same type, you can check for instance:

```js
if (b instanceof Array) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Array.isArray(a) && a.length === 0) {
  // a is an array and an empty one
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, using **typeof** for both Objects and Arrays will return **Object**.
There are certain methods in JS to check if a variable is an array or not.

1. *Array.isArray(variableName)*
2. *variableName  instanceof Array*
3. *variableName.constructor === Array*

All these Methods will return **true** if variable is an array else will return **false**.